# $count does not return 0 when no documents found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count, aggregation-framework, stage

I have the following aggregation pipeline in mongoDB:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "total": [
        {
          "$count": "rows"
        }
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "$skip": 0
        },
        {
          "$limit": 200
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "total": {
        "$first": "$total.rows"
      },
      "data": 1
    }
  }
]
```

The aggregation works fine if there are matches:
for example: aggregation result (in case there are 2 documents in my collection)

```
{
  data: [{firstName: "Bob"}, {firstName: "Marry"}],
  total: 2
}
```

But it's not working good when there are NO matches:
This is what the aggregation returns (in case there are 0 documents in my collection)

```
{
  data: []
}
```

I don't get why in case there is not matches, the total is not returned with 0, like this:

```
{
  data: [],
  total: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the aggregation framework operates in general.

If you'd like to always have a number there, then you could include a `$ifNull` check for `total`:

```
      "total": {
        "$ifNull": [
          {
            "$first": "$total.rows"
          },
          0,
          {
            "$first": "$total.rows"
          }
        ]
      }
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TrPRjOgBvqg)

For what it's worth, you also don't need the `$match` at the beginning if no filter is being provided to it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your informative comment.
it's exactly what I need.